# SSIS 2008 task dependency configuration

Tags: sql-server, email, for-loop, ssis

I have a package that before any ETL happens it checks source tables to ensure they exist. If they do not exist, it sends me an email via send mail task then waits 30 mins via execute sql task, before trying again via for loop container.

I'm trying to configure this package so if it loops, and then finally succeeds I get an email telling me succeeded.  But I don't want an email EVERY time it succeeds, just if the loop occurred and then finished.

So if the source data does not exist, do not proceed to next container, instead send me an email, wait 30 mins, and try again.  If finally the source tables appear, then proceed to next container, and send me an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your steps correctly, you have an `Execute SQL Task` which checks for the schema, if schema is not present sends an email and then waits for 30 mins and loops back again to check the schema. You can add a `boolean` variable say `SendSucessEmail` which can be set with something like this

```
DECLARE @SendSucessEmail BIT = 0

WHILE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT TOP 1 1 
FROM sys.tables where name = 'checktable'
)
BEGIN
SET @SendSucessEmail = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'

END

SELECT @SendSucessEmail AS SucessEmailVariable
```

In your package, You can get this value and use it to send your email.